# socket.io 3.0 show different views/templates for room based on user

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a chat application in which I want to display a separate view/template for the creator of the room and for everyone else.

I thought about something like pass an creator argument as boolean to the user who joined and make an if statement. But this looks like a bad design so I would ask here for help. I would like to set up a different view based on the user created status (true or false).

What I try to archive is to have 2 seperate html files and I want to implement that based on the creator argument the regarding template is rendered.

Comment: Note: the `sockets` tag is for lower level IO sockets (i.e., raw TCP/IP, UDP, etc'). It is unrelated to `socket.io` (except in the sense that `socket.io` will use the lower level layer under the hood). I removed the `sockets` tag from your question since it was confusing.